# arduino custom msg

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, can anybody point me in the right direction as to how to set up custom ROS messages for the arduino? I am using rosserial_arduino. I've tried a number of things, and I keep running into path/compilation problems. I haven't had any luck in finding anything. Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12010/arduino-custom-msg/) by [Fred99](https://answers.ros.org/users/1423/fred99/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you followed the [tutorial in rosserial_client](http://ros.org/wiki/rosserial_client/Tutorials/Generating%20Message%20Header%20Files)?

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fred99](https://answers.ros.org/users/1423/fred99/) on 2011-11-22**:
No I didn't. I tried the other ones, but missed that one Thank you very much!

**Comment by [Chubba_07](https://answers.ros.org/users/45484/chubba_07/) on 2019-09-08**:
i couldnt get it done even after following the steps given in the tutorial. I am new to ros .It would be helpful if you could give me detailed answer for the above query